# Inconsistent scrollbars between different browsers

Tags: css, scrollbar

IE: http://666kb.com/i/c6fufhslm58tzh66k.jpg
Chrome: http://666kb.com/i/c6fufwh0ebfrcgwi4.jpg

php code:

```
echo"<div id='anamain'>";
echo"<iframe frameborder=0 scrolling=yes width=100% height=100% src='duello.php'></iframe>";
echo"</div>";
```

css code:

```
#anamain
{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
    left:25%;
    top:205px;
    border-width:1px;
    width:50%;
    height:auto;
    color:#9db4bd;
}
```

How can I solve this difference issue? I want the way of Chrome view.

Comment: Welcome to CSS styling! Each browser handles things differently. You're going to have to deal with it.

Comment: clearfix? Maybe put together a fiddle.

Comment: @rlemon Jeah! http://jsfiddle.net/WqJYG/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each browser has a slightly different default state for page elements. Typically, one uses a "CSS Reset" to mitigate these differences.

Check out http://www.cssreset.com/ for more info

That being said, the differences are not all going to be addressed by a reset stylesheet. Some elements just behave differently in different browsers, **especially** when you're dealing with that maniacal, child-eating deviant known as Internet Explorer.

Understanding this, for your purposes you can force scrollbars by using the css `overflow` properties

```
#anamain
{
    /* ... previous styles ... */
    overflow: scroll;
    /* OR overflow: hidden; to hide */
    /* OR overflow-y: scroll; */
    /* OR overflow-x: scroll; */
}
```

Specific to your problem, it looks like you'll actually need to apply the `overflow` style to the iframe, rather than the containing div. I've put together a sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/WqJYG/

As you can see, applying the `overflow: hidden;` style to both the wrapping div AND the iframe ensures you don't get any scroll bars.

**Documentation**

- `overflow` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow
- `overflow-y` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow-y
- `overflow-x` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow-x

Comment: This helped me about learning CSS a lot but it always always allllwayys showing scroll bar and view of frame is not changing anytime I try.

Comment: Take a look at the jsFiddle example -- the technique works, as long as other CSS is not a factor. On jsFiddle, there is no other CSS, the code works. on your site... there is other CSS, the code doesn't work. Therefore, the problem is probably ________? (Hint: get Firebug! :D)

Comment: @Slavez oops, forgot to tag ya! :D